# New version of Skype does not work as expected, how to install the older version?

Tags: skype

New version of Skype 4.0.0.8 does not work as expected, how to install the older version? Please help me, new version of skype really has many bugs in it, I want to use older version which is much simpler, but much more convenient. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you have two possibilities:

Solution 1: delete the "new skype", download skype 2.2 from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/maya/import/base/skype, install it.

There is a chance that ubuntu will update skype again, the next time you do an update, what brings us to solution 2.

Solution 2: Use the static version of skype 2.2 like spyroboy explains on superuser.com

> if you download the statically linked (not requiring system dependancies) skype >distributable, you can run both Skype 4.0 and Skype 2.2 on the same system.
>
> install skype 4.0 using the deb, and download the statically linked version of skype >2.2 and extract it to /opt and then add /opt/skype-VERSION to your $PATH in ~/.bashrc
>
> rename the skype executable in /opt/skype-VERSION to something like skype-2.2
>
> and once you've done all of that, you should be able to run skype-2.2 and skype for >either version.
>
> here's Skype 2.2 static: http://download.skype.com/linux/skype_static-2.2.0.35.tar.bz2

hopefully you understand what to do, if not, just askubuntu ;)

Good Luck!

Comment: The 2.2 static version contains an executable skype. It can be run from its folder. It is really better than the new version.